# Find the maximum of $S(x,y) = 3x^3-4xy^2+y$

Tags: calculus, optimization

> Let $A(x,y)$ be a point inside or on a regular hexagon of side length $10$ centered at the origin of the $xy$-plane with a pair of sides parallel to the $x$-axis. If $S(x,y) = 3x^3-4xy^2+y$, find $\lfloor \max\{S(x,y)\} \rfloor$.

This question is basically asking us for the maximum value of $f(x,y) = 3x^3-4xy^2+y$ on the hexagonal set for $(x,y)$. This is not a simple question like "find the maximum of $S(x,y) = 3x^3-4xy^2+y$ for all $x,y$." So I am wondering how it is possible to solve this question. Do we even need to think about this question in terms of a function or maybe there is an easier way to see it just by looking at the $x,y$  plane or even algebraically? Also we could use Lagrange multipliers but we would have to break it into $6$ cases and still deal with the range issue.

Comment: The necessary conditions $\partial S/\partial x=0, \partial S/\partial y=0,$ are not sufficient because the Hessian $H$ of $S$ is not definite positive ($det(H)=-144x^2-64y^2<0$). Thus the maximum is on the boundary. By breaking into 6 cases, as you propose, but without using Lagrange multipliers, I find that the maximum occurs in $(10,0)$ with value $3000$. I will maybe write it dowm as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hessian $H$ of $S$ is not definite positive ($det(H)=-144x^2-64y^2 \leq 0$.)

Thus no true maxima can exist (in particular, conditions $\partial S/\partial x=0, \partial S/\partial y=0$ are not applicable). Due to domain restriction (the inside of a certain hexagon), the maximum or maxima are to be found on the boundary of this hexagon.

We are going to inspect only the upper part of the boundary ($y \geq 0$), which is divided into 3 sides, numberes (1), (2) and (3), with resp. equations given underneath (we proceed in the classical positive order of angles). The 3 other sides can be treated in the same way, using the important property that $\forall x,y \ S(-x,-y)=-S(x,y)$.

$$ (1) \ y=\sqrt{3}(10-x) \ \ \ \ \ \ (2) \ y= 5\sqrt{3}, \ \ \ \ \ \ (3) \  y=\sqrt{3}(10+x)$$

or

$$ (1) \ x=10-y/\sqrt{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ (2) \ y= 5\sqrt{3}, \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)  \ x=-10+y/\sqrt{3}$$

Before proceeding, let us remark that: $ \ \ 0 \leq y \leq 5\sqrt{3} \ \ (*)$

Plugging these expressions (1), (2), (3) in $S$ results into managable cases:

**Side 1**: We plug expression (1) into $S(x,y)$ resulting into

$\ \ T(y):=S(10-y/\sqrt{3},y)=3000+y(1-300\sqrt{3}+5y)+y^2(\sqrt{3}y-15)$

The two terms between parenthesis are both negative (taking into account relation ship (*)). Thus the maximum value on the first line segment of the boundary, 3000, is reached for $y=0$, and, subsequently $x=10$.

**Side 2** (in this case $|x| \leq 5$): $ \ T(x):=S(x,5\sqrt{3})=3x(x-100)+5\sqrt{3}$ is such that $|T(x)| \leq 3 \times 5 \times 100 + 5\sqrt{3} < 3000$. The maximum is not reached on this 2nd side.

**Side 3**: $ \ T(y):=S(10+y/\sqrt{3},y)=-3000+[y((1+300 \sqrt{3})-5y)]+[y^2(15-\sqrt{3}y)]$

Using relationship (*), the second expression between square brackets above does not exceed $b_2=75 \times 15=1125$. The first one  is bounded by $b_1=5 \sqrt{3}(1+300 \sqrt{3})=4500 + 5\sqrt{3}$. When added to $-3000$, $b_1+b_2$ give $T(y)$ a maximal value less than $3000$. Thus the maximum is not reached on this 3rd side.

**Conclusion** : the maximum value of $S(x,y)$ is $3000$, reached in $(x,y)=(10,0)$.